# Why is my interval of consecutive rdtsc calls periodic?

Tags: linux, performance, amazon-ec2, low-latency

I am profiling interval of consecutive rdtsc calls as suggested by [this talk by David Gross](https://youtu.be/8uAW5FQtcvE?t=2820).
My system is aws c5a.8xlarge instance, ubuntu 22.04 LTS server, no other user packages installed and there is no any other work load on it.

Each data point on below graph is the mean/std deviation of interval of 256 consecutive rdtsc calls. (eg. mean/std deviation of 255 intervals). I do the 256 calls once a second,

As you can see in the graph, it's periodic. Can anybody explain this for me? thanks.

The cpu frequncy is 2799.932 Mhz from cpuinfo. I converted the rdtsc value to nanosecond by dividing it with 2.799932.

[image]

The code of mean/std calculation for one data point is as below:

```cpp
std::pair<double, double> trial(std::size_t nSamples) {
    folly::fbvector<uint64_t> samples(nSamples);
    for (uint64_t& s : samples) {
        s = folly::hardware_timestamp();
    }

    folly::fbvector<uint64_t> diff1(nSamples-1);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nSamples-1; i++) {
        diff1[i] = samples[i+1] - samples[i];
    }
    std::cout << folly::format("{}, {}, {}", diff1[0], diff1[1], diff1[2]) << std::endl;

    double sum = std::accumulate(diff1.begin(), diff1.end(), 0.0);
    double mean = sum / diff1.size();

    folly::fbvector<double> diff1Diff(diff1.size());
    std::transform(diff1.begin(), diff1.end(), diff1Diff.begin(), [mean](double x) { return x - mean; });

    double sq_sum = std::inner_product(diff1Diff.begin(), diff1Diff.end(), diff1Diff.begin(), 0.0);
    double stddev = std::sqrt(sq_sum / diff1Diff.size());

    std::cout << folly::format("mean:{}, stddev:{}", mean, stddev) << std::endl;
    return std::make_pair(mean, stddev);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it is periodic. However, the c5a.8xlarge is a virtual server, isn't it? I wouldn't expect that to be a very good platform for low-latency or determinism.

Comment: Assuming it is not a virtual server (which seems to be), then there is no matching AMD 7002 processor operating at 2.8 GHz having 32 cores. Thus, what you see is likely the effect of a frequency scaling. Even if it is not, AFAIK there is no guarantee for the RDTSC instruction to take a fixed time. Modern processors are pretty complex and they are a lot of source of variability at this scale. If you are searching for a low-latency processor with fixed timings, then modern x86 processors are not a good choice (due to OoO, scheduling-based IPC, branch-prediction, prefetchers, etc.).